# query and Request issues with gtrendsr

Tags: gtrendsr

I have successfully logged in google account with

```
gconnect(usr,password)
```

But I got request problem when I want to query the data

```
gt.us <- gtrends("USA", geo="US", start_date="2004-01-01", end_date="2004-01-30")
```

> Error: Not enough search volume. Please change your search terms.
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In request_GET(x, url, ...) : Gone (HTTP 410).

Could anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

Get gtrendsR 2.0.0:

```
devtools::install_github('PMassicotte/gtrendsR')

library(gtrendsR)
# do not need to log in anymore
# syntax change!
gt.us <- gtrends("USA", geo="US", time = "2004-01-01 2004-01-30")
```

See Philippe Massicotte [answer to this issue](https://github.com/PMassicotte/gtrendsR/issues/108).